# Why can't ESA/NASA build a handful of Gaia telescopes and launch them into different positions in space for better accuracy?

Tags: orbit, deep-sky-observing, gaia, lagrange-point

I've noticed that many stars in GAIA DR2 have highly uncertain distances. Why can't a space agency send multiple Gaia spacecraft into orbit around different places (One in L2 Earth, one in heliosynchronous orbit, and one around Jupiter) so the accuracy  of observations can be greatly improved?

Comment: In the funding-doesn't-play-a-role-fairyland, sure they would to that.

Comment: Satellites are not cheap to build. Satellites are not cheap to launch. Satellites are not cheap to operate. Data from satellites is not cheap to process. Need I say more?

Comment: The premise that ESA "can't" isn't really true, they probably could if they had enough money and resources for it. It might be better to adjust your question and ask in what ways, and by how much would a second GAIA out at 5 AU improve data, and what the technical challenges would be. You might be surprised!

Comment: This is a different question but it's related: [How would 2 JWSTs make stereo pictures?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35548/12102)